# adding PHP variable to SQL statement. Not working

Tags: php, sql

I can't get a variable to work in SQL statement. I can get it to work when I replace (username = $user) with (ID = 11) which is another column from database and a specific row (11), but I want to include a specific row matching $user from column 'username', along with other random results with a limit of $sn.

When using var_dump($user) I know that the variable has a value, but can't see why it doesn't work in SQL statement.

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profile_images
WHERE approved='N'  
ORDER BY (username = $user) DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT $sn) 
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Getting error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@googlemail.com) DESC, RAND() LIMIT 9) as A ORDER BY RAND()' at line 4

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$sn` holds integer value and don't require escaping,

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM ( 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profile_images 
WHERE approved='N'   
ORDER BY (username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."') DESC, RAND()       
LIMIT $sn)  
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

In general, consider using PDO and bind parameters.

Comment: Have cast $sn to integer using intval. Not quite sure what PDO and bind parameters are but will look them up. Thanks for your help.